# al guardar fecha con java.sql.date me guarda un día antes

Tags: java, mysql

tengo un código para modificar los datos de las reservas de un hotel. Cuando selecciono el dato de la tabla y lo cambio, me queda guardado un día antes de la fecha que modifiqué.
Aquí está mi código:

```
`private void modificarReserva() {
            if(tieneFilaElegidaReservas()) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Por favor, elije un item");
                return;
            }
            
            Optional.ofNullable(modelo.getValueAt(tbReservas.getSelectedRow(), tbReservas.getSelectedColumn()))
                .ifPresent(fila->{
                    Integer id = Integer.valueOf(modelo.getValueAt(tbReservas.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString());
                    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    String fechaEntrada = (String) modelo.getValueAt(tbReservas.getSelectedRow(), 1).toString();
                    java.sql.Date fechaEntradaSQL = null;
                    String fechaSalida = (String) modelo.getValueAt(tbReservas.getSelectedRow(), 2).toString();
                    java.sql.Date fechaSalidaSQL = null;
                    try {
                        Date parsedFE = dateFormat.parse(fechaEntrada);
                        fechaEntradaSQL = new java.sql.Date(parsedFE.getTime());
                        Date parsedFS = dateFormat.parse(fechaSalida);
                        fechaSalidaSQL = new java.sql.Date(parsedFS.getTime());
                        
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    
                    Double valor = Double.valueOf(modelo.getValueAt(tbReservas.getSelectedRow(), 3).toString());
                    String formaPago = (String) modelo.getValueAt(tbReservas.getSelectedRow(), 4);
                    
                    Reservas reserva = new Reservas(id,fechaEntradaSQL, fechaSalidaSQL, valor, formaPago);
                    this.reservasController.modificar(reserva);
                    
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Reserva " +id+" actualizada");
                });
        }`
```

El código selecciona de la tabla las fechas en un tipo String(Son las variables fechaEntrada y fechaSalida), luego las convierto al tipo Date con las variables parsedFE y parseFS, por último las guardo tipo java.sql.Date y las envío a otro método para guardarlas en la Base de Datos.

Pero a la hora de guardarlas me guarda un día antes de la fecha que puse.
Alguien sabe cómo arreglar esto? Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: intenta con el util date de toda la vida

Comment: Pero no lo puedo enviar a la Base de Datos como util Date. Osea...En un punto de código lo convierto a util Date, en las variables parsedFE y parsedFS. Para luego convertirlas a sql Date y enviarlas a la DB.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614836/using-setdate-in-preparedstatement/38809770#38809770

Comment: ¿Puede ser que el servidor de base de datos no tenga configurada la zona horaria igual que el servidor donde está la aplicación? Eso explicaría la diferencia de un día.

Comment: @GavilanPatagonico tenías razón. Era un problema con la Zona Horaria.  //es.stackoverflow.com/questions/168663/porque-java-resta-un-día-a-la-fecha-obtenida-de-un-executequery-ejecutado-a-la-b Aquí pude encontrar más información al respecto, por si alguien le surge el mismo problema.